# Invalid hook call while testing with jest - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, jestjs, rtk-query

I've got problem with testing screen. I'm trying to test with `jest snapshot` but first of all I wan't to pass simple test with `RTK Query request` `API`. In next example I try to get error something like `Test didn't pass due to not equal results` but I'm getting `Invalid hook call` and more will be next to example code.

`ContactScreen-test.js`

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { useGetUserDataQuery } from '../../services';

describe("testing", () => {
  test("should working properly", () => {
    const result = useGetUserDataQuery();
    console.log(result);
    expect(result).toBe("Idk what");
  });
});
```

Which getting query from `services.ts` /

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { RootState } from '../src/redux/store';

export interface UserResponse {
  data: {
    access_token: string;
    expires_in: number;
    refresh_token: string;
    role: string;
  };
}

export interface LoginRequest {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const device_id = '38bda1ce-f795-5cb8-8ae7-4c30b874';

export const callApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'api link here',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.access_token;

      if (device_id) {
        headers.set('Device_Id', device_id);
        headers.set('Authorization', `${token}`);
      }
      return headers;
    }
  }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    login: builder.mutation<UserResponse, LoginRequest>({
      query: data => ({
        url: '/sessions',
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      })
    }),
    getUserData: builder.query({
      query: (arg: void) => ({ url: `users/me/`, body: arg })
    }),
    getOfficeData: builder.query({
      query: (office_id: string) => ({ url: `office_contacts/${office_id}` })
    })
  })
});

export const { useLoginMutation, useGetOfficeDataQuery, useGetUserDataQuery } =
  callApi;
```

and error which I'm getting is:

```
 Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

       8 | describe("testing", () => {
       9 |   test("should working properly", () => {
    > 10 |     const result = useGetUserDataQuery();
         |                    ^
      11 |     console.log(result);
      12 |     expect(result).toBe("Idk what");
      13 |   });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't test hooks as you would test a normal function.

For testing hooks, you should use [react-hooks-testing-library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/).

You would probably need to do something like

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import { useGetUserDataQuery } from '../../services';

test('should working properly', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useGetUserDataQuery())
  expect(result).toBe("Idk what");
})
```

Comment: Okay got It, but my goal Isn't to tests hooks but whole screen/component. If I can't put hooks like that, then what should I do?

Like these docs write down:
`When not to use this library

   1. Your hook is defined alongside a component and is only used there
   2. Your hook is easy to test by just testing the components using it` All of the points are true

Comment: @MikołajWittbrodt If you want to test the whole screen/component, you shouldn't call the hook function directly. For that you would probably use [react-native-testing-library](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/) and let the component you are testing call the hook